Generating a clamped B-Spline
I am trying to display a clamped B-Spline curve.  ( That is, one where the curve starts on the first control point and ends on last control point )
Here is the input:
Control points
    xcp = {
        5, 5, 16, 31, 22, 33, 44, 42, 51, 50, 59};
    ycp = {
        27, 12, 29, 18, 9, 9, 20, 29, 28, 10, 10};

Knots
    vknot = {
        0.0,        0.0,        0.0,        0.0,        
        1.0,        2.0,        3.0,        4.0,        5.0,        6.0,        7.0,
        8.0,        8.0,        8.0,        8.0};

Note the repeated knot values at beginning and end - that is what should clamp the curve.  See https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve.html
I have tried implementing the described algorithm here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/B-Spline.html
Here is my code
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


class CSpline
{
public:
    int m_ControlPointCount;

    std::vector<double> xcp, ycp, vknot;

    double current;

    void generateInput();

    bool getNextPoint(int &xp, int &yp);

private:
    double BSN(int i, int j, double t);
};

CSpline theSpline;

void CSpline::generateInput()
{
    vknot = {
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        1.0,
        2.0,
        3.0,
        4.0,
        5.0,
        6.0,
        7.0,
        8.0,
        8.0,
        8.0,
        8.0};
    if (fabs(1 - vknot.back()) > 0.01)
    {
        // normalize knot values
        for (double &v : vknot)
            v /= vknot.back();
    }
    xcp = {
        5, 5, 16, 31, 22, 33, 44, 42, 51, 50, 59};
    ycp = {
        27, 12, 29, 18, 9, 9, 20, 29, 28, 10, 10};

    current = 0;
}

bool CSpline::getNextPoint(int &xp, int &yp)
{
    // number of points drawn along curve
    const int Ndiv = 100;
    if (current == Ndiv)
        return false;
    double t = current / Ndiv;
    int degree = vknot.size() - xcp.size() - 1;

    double x,y;
    x = y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < xcp.size(); i++)
    {
        double N = BSN(i, degree, t);
        x += xcp[i] * N;
        y += ycp[i] * N;
    }

    std::cout << t <<" "<< x <<" "<< y << "\n";

    current++;

    return true;
}

double CSpline::BSN(int i, int j, double t)
{
    if (j == 0)
    {
        if (vknot[i] <= t && t < vknot[i + 1] &&
            vknot[i] < vknot[i + 1])
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    double adiv = vknot[i + j] - vknot[i];
    double bdiv = vknot[i + j + 1] - vknot[i + 1];
    if (fabs(adiv) < 0.00001 || fabs(bdiv) < 0.00001) {
        std::cout << "warning zero div\n";
        return 0;
    }
    double a = (t - vknot[i]) / adiv;
    double b = (vknot[i + j + 1] - t) / bdiv;
    return a * BSN(i, j - 1, t) + b * BSN(i + 1, j - 1, t);
}

main()
{
    theSpline.generateInput();

    int x, y;
    while( theSpline.getNextPoint(x,y))
        ;

    cGUI theGUI;
    return 0;
}

The code causes numerous divide by zero problems
This happens because
double adiv = vknots[i+j] - vknots[i];

is zero when i = 0 and j = 3
because

I have tried increasing the degree ( more knots ) but the same thing happens deeper in the recursive calls to BSN as J becomes small enough.
I have tried returning 0 or 1 instead of throwing an exception, but the resulting points on the curve are nonsense rather than clamping.
( Side note 1: the code seems to work OK if the spline is not clamped )
( Side note 2: I am aware of this question ( B-Splines in C++ ).  There the spline is NOT clamped )

The best algorithm for calculation a good BSpline curve does seem to be deBoor.  I have looked at several descriptions of this algorithm on the web.  IMHO they are all inadequate in that they do not describe their parameters and usage. Some have errors in the sample code.
For me, the best is on Wikipedia ( it still does not properly explain the input variables but gives enough clues that it can be fixed with some work )
python code from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor%27s_algorithm#Example_implementation
    def deBoor(k: int, x: int, t, c, p: int):
    """Evaluates S(x).

    Arguments
    ---------
    k: Index of knot interval that contains x.
    x: Position.
    t: Array of knot positions, needs to be padded as described above.
    c: Array of control points.
    p: Degree of B-spline.
    """
    d = [c[j + k - p] for j in range(0, p + 1)]

    for r in range(1, p + 1):
        for j in range(p, r - 1, -1):
            alpha = (x - t[j + k - p]) / (t[j + 1 + k - r] - t[j + k - p])
            d[j] = (1.0 - alpha) * d[j - 1] + alpha * d[j]

    return d[p]

Note 1:  input x "the position" is declared to be an integer.  This makes no sense.
IMHO this should be a double in the range [0,1] where 0 is the first point and 1 is the last.
[] indicates end points included in range
Note 2: input c: array of control points is an array of values for one dimension of the control points
for a 2D curve this must be called twice, once for the x values and once for the y values
Here is my port to C++
    /// @brief deBoor algorithm for B-Spline generation
    /// @param k index of greatest knot less than x
    /// @param x position along the curve in the range [0,1] where 0 is the first point and 1 is the last.
    /// @param t knots in the range [0,1] where 0 is the first point and 1 is the last
    /// @param c values for one dimension of the control points ( e.g x or y for 2D curve)
    /// @param p degree of spline 
    /// @return value of spline curve in dimenson provided by c
    ///
    /// call this once for each dimension of the curve

    double deBoor(
        int k,
        double x,
        const std::vector<double> &t,
        const std::vector<double> &c,
        int p)
    {
        std::vector<double> d;
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < p + 1; j1++)
            d.push_back(c[j1 + k - p]);

        for (int r = 1; r < p + 2; r++)
        {
            for (int j = p; j > r - 1; j--)
            {
                double alpha = (x - t[j + k - p]) / (t[j + 1 + k - r] - t[j + k - p]);
                d[j] = (1 - alpha) * d[j - 1] + alpha * d[j];
            }
        }
        return d[p];
    }

This gives a decent result with the input data given in my question


This might not an answer your question but it should lead to your answer.

Common inputs for creating B-Spline are control point list, knot list and degree. Your degree got by calculate this seem isn't correct.
To create clamped B-Spline we need adjust input by repeat last knots and add first control points to the end of list (should be same number with degree). So your control point list seem isn't for create clamped B-Spline.
We can use De Boor's algorithm for create common B-Spline de-Boor.

I was success to implement B-Spline here mine.
 struct Spline {
      std::vector<Vec3> control_points;
      std::vector<double> knots;
      std::vector<double> weights;
      int16_t degree = 2;

  };
 struct SplineGen {
        using point_type = Vec3;
        using iterator = math::SegmentIter<SplineGen, point_type, point_type>;

        SplineGen(const Spline& _sp)
            :sp{ _sp }
        {
            gen_component(10);
        }

        //--start deboor algorithm
        double basis(double u, int i, int p) const
        {
            if (p == 0) {
                return (sp.knots[i] <= u && u < sp.knots[i + 1]) ? 1. : 0.;
            }
            double a = 0.0;
            double b = 0.0;
            if (sp.knots[i + p] != sp.knots[i]) {
                a = (u - sp.knots[i]) / (sp.knots[i + p] - sp.knots[i]) * basis(u, i, p - 1);
            }
            if (sp.knots[i + p + 1] != sp.knots[i + 1]) {
                b = (sp.knots[i + p + 1] - u) / (sp.knots[i + p + 1] - sp.knots[i + 1]) * basis(u, i + 1, p - 1);
            }
            return a + b;
        }

        point_type at(double u) const
        {
            point_type result{};
            for (int i = 0;i <= sp.control_points.size(); ++i) {
                auto w = sp.weights.empty() ? 1. : sp.weights[i];
                result += basis(u, i, sp.degree) * w * sp.control_points[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
        //--end deboor algorithm

        point_type operator()(int t) const
        {
            return at(sp.knots.front() + (static_cast<double>(t) / seg) * knot_len);
        }


        void gen_component(int knot_seg)
        {
            seg = sp.knots.size() * knot_seg;
            knot_len = sp.knots.back() - sp.knots.front();
        }


        iterator begin() const { return iterator{ 0, *this }; }
        iterator end() const
        {
            return iterator{ seg, *this }; 
        }
        int size() const
        {
            return seg;
        }
    private:
        const Spline& sp;
        int seg;
        double knot_len;
    };


My Vec3
struct Vec3
{
    Vec3() = default;
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;
};
Vec3& operator+=(Vec3& a, const Vec3& b)
{
   a.x += b.x;
   a.y += b.y;
   a.z += b.z;
   return a;
}
Vec3 operator+(const Vec3& a, const Vec3& b)
{
   return { a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z };
}
Vec3 operator*(const Vec3& a, double s)
{
   return { a.x * s, a.y * s, a.z * s };
}
Vec3 operator*(double s, const Vec3& v)
{
   return v * s;
}

It's look similar to your. My spline require vector3D and weights you can ignore them. My Spline generator is implement c++ iterator but it isn't necessary.

"Your degree got by calculate this seem isn't correct."  I used the formula to calculate degree specified in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/B-Spline.html.   p=m-n-1.  Is this incorrect?  Can you explain why your code sets the degree to 2, seemingly out of the blue.

Your code does not build.  There are no #include statements and no main()

Your code uses Vec3.  What is that?

@ravenspoint My function use for generate Spline from CAD data format (dxf). Their software could change degree when user want to create Spline and default is 2.
Your xcp, ycp (X, Y)  call Scalar quantity and My Vec3 (X, Y, Z)  call Vector quantity. Vector quantity can do same operation as Scalar quantity (plus, multiply (actually called scale for Vector)). Your can replace my Vec3 with your own.

@ravenpoint You might not familiar with c++ overload operator. I added definition for Vec3.

Your code STILL does not build.  Where is your test input?  Is it clamped?
